# Scala Play Framework - Dynamic Forms

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm currently in the process of trying to define a dynamic form in Play (Scala). What I mean by a "dynamic" form is one which presents different form elements (and POSTs different data) depending on the state of some runtime (specifically database-side) data.

A brief illustrative example: on a to-do list application, how could one create a form which creates a "delete" check box next to each of the list elements? I realize this could be done with GET links or with AJAX/javascript, but I want this to be a standard POST form with a "submit" button.

I'm aware of the repeated mapping form functionality, but is it possible to define an even more dynamically generated form, where the structure is less strict than just single+repeated elements?

Thanks for any suggestions you might have. I realize this might just be more than POST is cut out for.

Comment: For the todo list/html only use case, just wrap one form around each row. I seem to remember that you can have multiple submit buttons with different values, you could do delete/update buttons that way.

Comment: Richard, thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, that method would preclude batched form submission; you'd only be able to select one check box (and then hit the submit button for that box) at a time. This would work in this simple case, but not for the more complex targets I am actually implementing.

Comment: No worries! I think you're going to need javascript.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I'm starting to think as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing that I have to an answer for this is that POST and any sane web framework supports "array" inputs. Hence, if you can get your data into any regularized format, you can serialize/deserialize via that. You may be able to support semiexotic data patterns by using this method as well.